# Ring Isomorphisms

Tags: ring-theory, integers, group-isomorphism

Why are   $\mathbb{Z} [\sqrt{2}]$  and   $\mathbb{Z} [ \sqrt {2} ]   \times   \mathbb{Z} [ \sqrt {2} ]$ not isomorphic to each other?

Put this question off for like a week while studying but I feel there is a very simple answer.  I think it might have to do with commutativity.

-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former is a domain and the latter is not a domain.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{2}]$ is a domain.

Comment: AND THE OTHER ONE ISN'T!

Answer (score 0):

If $\,R\ne 0\,$ then a ring hom from $\,R \times R\,$ to a domain maps the $\,3\,$ roots $\,(0,0),(1,1),(0,1)\,$ of $\,x^2 = x\,$ onto the $\,2\,$ roots $\,0,1\,$ in the domain, so the hom is not injective.